# Get code of project being built and place into a directory

Tags: tfs

I want to write a TFS task which will get the code of the project being built and put it into a directory on the build agent for burning to a cd.

How could I get the code and put it into a directory?

Thanks

Comment: I had originally answered this based on that you wanted the executables copied to a specific location.  Do you want the actual source code?

Answer (score 0):

Since the code being built is already being pulled down (so it can be built), you could simply use the [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) MSBuild task to copy the desired source code files to another folder.  The root of the source code is available via the **$(SolutionRoot)** MSBuild property.